Phi-3 can't deal with Japanese. How can I solve this issue?
I enjoy Phi-3 which Microsoft made.
I meet the error of onnxruntime_genai. onnxruntime_genai is library of Phi-3.
How can I solve this issue ?
import onnxruntime_genai as og

list_error = [234, 170, 132, 233, 161, 147, 232, 146, 145, 174, 152, 183, 141, 188, 138, 148, 182, 178, 162, 236, 139, 231, 189, 187, 175, 235]

model = og.Model(".\Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct-onnx\cpu_and_mobile\cpu-int4-rtn-block-32")
tokenizer = og.Tokenizer(model)
tokenizer_stream = tokenizer.create_stream()

for new_token in list_error:
    print(tokenizer_stream.decode(new_token), end='', flush=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 2
      1 for new_token in list_error:
----> 2     print(tokenizer_stream.decode(new_token), end='', flush=True)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: unexpected end of data

UnicodeDecodeError is occurred in tokenizer_stream.decode.
But I can' see the source code of onnxruntime_genai.

https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-genai/issues/314
